# how to check whether value of a variable contain numbers vs value is a number in R

Tags: r, contains

I have the following R data frame. the column "state" is a **factor** column.
I have 2 questions:

1- I want to create a flag as to whether each row (value of state) is a number or 
character. 1 if character and 0 if number

```
ID   state
 1   123fg^>
 2   fhgfh@
 3   125@!
 4   125
```

and i want the output to look like this

```
ID   state   Flag
 1   123fg^>    1
 2   fhgfh@     1
 3   125@!      1
 4   125        0
```

2- Next, I want to create a flag of 1 or 0 if a cell contains numbers. so for the same example i want to have the following output

```
ID   state   Flag
 1   123fg^>    1
 2   fhgfh@     0
 3   125@!      1
 4   125        1
```

Comment: What if 'state' == '', an empty string? What if it is just punctuation, e.g. ',.'?

Comment: For "is a number or a character", there's `is.na(as.numeric(DF$state))`, ie checking if coercion to numeric works...

Answer (score 5):

We can use `grep` for both the cases to match one or more numbers (`[0-9]+`) from start (`^`) to end (`$`)

```
as.integer(!grepl("^[0-9]+$", df$state))
#[1] 1 1 0
```

or one or more letters (`[A-Za-z]+`) from start to end, do a negation (`!`) and convert the logical vector to binary

```
as.integer(!grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", df$state))
#[1] 1 0 1
```

Comment: What if the string contains punctuation? `as.integer(!grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", "!?"))`

Comment: @Mark In the examples, OP didn't provide that case

Comment: perfect. my other question is what if values of state had symbols like >,?,$ ..etc. I tried your code but it doesnt run as it gives error for values with symbols

Comment: @sahboor  The new question/example is not in your post

Comment: Or maybe something like `lapply(c("\\D", "\\d", "[[:punct:]]"), grepl, DF$state)`, ignoring the OP's desire for 0/1 instead of FALSE/TRUE.

Comment: I modified my example again

Comment: @sahboor  The first code still works.  The second code should be as Mark mentioned in the solution `as.integer(grepl("[0-9]", df2$state))`

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more robust numeric detection method (building on akrun's answer)

```
as.integer(grepl("[0-9]",df$state))
#> [1] 1 0 1
```

Since you ask for a string which contains numbers, this is a simpler solution and also handles the case of pure punctuation.

```
as.integer(grepl("[0-9]","!?"))
#> [1] 0
as.integer(!grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", "?!"))
#> [1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `gsub` can be as:

```
as.numeric(gsub("[0-9]|\\.","",df$state) != "")
[1] 1 1 1 0
```

`|\\.` => This will allow detecting even numbers with fraction (i.e. 125.8)